# Copy & paste between layers crashes program

Tags: qgis, windows-10, minidump

I attempted to copy a feature in one layer and paste it into another layer, as I have often done. However, I got the message, "Crash dumped; minidump written to c:\Users..." The program then closed itself.

I uninstalled the program, restarted the computer, and reinstalled the latest version, 2.14.21.

Upon starting the program, I get the yellow exclamation mark message, "Plugin processing: The plugin will be disabled because it crashed QGIS during last startup...re-enable the plugin when the problem has been solved."

When I click on "Plugins" in the main menu, I get a list, and the explanation that ones showing in red have a problem. However, none of mine are red.

When I again try to copy and paste from one layer to another, I still have the problem—even using different layers.

Any idea what's going on, and what I might do about it? I am running Windows 10.

Comment: Latest LTR is 2.18.15 by the way

Comment: I got scared off from 2.18 because the download page indicated that 2.14 is most stable. However I just installed 2.18--and still have the same problem. This time I got the message "qgis-bin.exe has stopped working" and it shut down. However I am not getting the message about a plugin problem...